# Is it good practice to teach using real life experiences of the student?

Tags: tutoring

I am not a professional teacher but I have students that seek me for clarification and knowledge. At times I use their personal real life experiences like how they relate to others to simplify the answer. Is it right professionally? 
In the case of programming, when teaching of classes, using their families to signify inheritance. For example your father was tall so will you be... your mother is intelligent so will you be... with no interest of motivate them but educate them.

Comment: Why would it not be?

Comment: How old they are ? which level they are ? Bachelor / Master or school kids? in which region? which kind of certificate you have ? ...

Comment: Careful. For example, when you teach inheritance using parents example, most students think about inheritance from their parents, but some may think about other things: why they don't have any parents? Why their parents ...? Those students would hate you for bringing that up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More broadly, upon observation, it seems that far more people learn by *analogy* than by strictly logical deductions. And, naturally, "analogy" means reference to their prior experience (as opposed to non-reference, that is, discussion "in a vacuum", for all the purity that that may confer).

Yes, there is a significant issue of avoiding accidental insults or clumsy remarks, so a little prior thought is very necessary. (It is almost impossible to un-do a bad impression/feeling made by unfortunate remarks, even if they were just accidental.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes - to answer your question. If it helps them understand the materials then you should do it.